# Ambiguity accessing identifier in global and nested anonymous namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

The following code:

```
namespace { constexpr int x = 1; }
namespace X { namespace { constexpr int x = 2; } }
using namespace X;

int main() {
  static_assert( ::x == 1 );
}
```

successfully compiles in MSVC, which prefers the first anonymous namespace in finding of `::x` over `X::(anonymous namespace)`.

However both GCC and Clang reject the code due to ambiguity of selection. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zPEGzGar3

Which compiler is right here?

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar example in this reference of [unnamed namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces):

```cpp
namespace {
    int i; // defines ::(unique)::i
}
void f() {
    i++;   // increments ::(unique)::i
}
 
namespace A {
    namespace {
        int i;        // A::(unique)::i
        int j;        // A::(unique)::j
    }
    void g() { i++; } // A::(unique)::i++
}
 
using namespace A; // introduces all names from A into global namespace
void h() {
    i++;    // error: ::(unique)::i and ::A::(unique)::i are both in scope
    A::i++; // ok, increments ::A::(unique)::i
    j++;    // ok, increments ::A::(unique)::j
}
```

According to this, rejecting the code due to ambiguity of selection by GCC and Clang should be correct.

> Namespaces provide a method for preventing name conflicts in large
> projects.
>
> Symbols declared inside a namespace block are placed in a named scope
> that prevents them from being mistaken for identically-named symbols
> in other scopes.

As this explanation states, `namespace` is introduced to avoid or solve the **name conflicts**. IMHO these code examples are obviously trying to make name conflicts.

Comment: Example might be *"different"*: qualified name lookup versus unqualified name lookup.

Comment: Notice that [qualified_lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) takes also into account the `using namespace`.

Comment: @Jarod42 _qualified_lookup takes also into account the `using namespace`_ What does «also» mean? That unqualified doesn't?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: One might consider that `using namespace` only applies to unqualified (that was my first idea before checking especially since I saw `::std::xxx` usage instead of `std::xxx` (which is so useless) in some std lib implementation). So *"also"* was for *"as unqualified lookup"*.